# Create generic Swift instance with static variable

Tags: swift, generics

I have a small generic Swift struct that looks like this:

```
public protocol FilterOption: Equatable {

    var name: String { get }
}

public struct Filter<T: FilterOption> {

    public init(selected: [T], available: [T]) {
        self.selected = selected
        self.available = available
    }

    public static var empty: Filter<T> {
        return Filter(selected: [], available: [])
    }

    public let available: [T]
    public let selected: [T]
}
```

However, I am at a loss as to how to call `.empty` in any other context than as a fallback or alternate result.

For instance, if `myFilter` is `nil`, this works:

```
let filter = myFilter ?? .empty
```

Another example is to have a conditional result, like this:

```
let filter = useFilter ? myFilter : .empty
```

These cases work and are reasons alone to have the `empty` var, but I have no idea how to just create an empty filter.

For instance, this doesn't work:

```
let filter: Filter<UserFilter> = .empty
```

and fails with the error message `'Filter' is ambiguous for type lookup in this context`.

This also doesn't work:

```
let filter = Filter<Language>.empty
```

and fails with the error message `Cannot specialize a non-generic definition`.

How can I provide type information when creating an empty filter? Is this even possible?

Comment: Without `FilterOption` I cannot reproduce your error. So please include the definition of `FilterOption` in your question.

Comment: I tried replacing your `FilterOption` protocol with `StringProtocol` and then creating an empty filter by `let emptyFilter = Filter<String>.empty`. Everything works fine. You may have missed the `FilterOption` protocol conformance on your `UserFilter`/`Language` type.

Comment: Code in the question works. Your problem is somewhere else in your project. You should expand your question.

Comment: Yes, I found that the `FilterOption` conformance for my types (user filter was just an example here) was not correctly exposed. As soon as the compiler found it, everything worked. Thank you!

Comment: @nayem If you feel like posting your comment as an answer, I'll mark is as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the question doesn't need a separate answer as the code is supposed to work provided that the generic placeholder is satisfied properly. It should be salvageable by the comment I made in the question. But as you have asked, I've converted my comment to a detailed answer.

The concrete type that you are providing to the generic placeholder must conform to the protocol (for your case it's `FilterOption`). Like you have defined:

```
let filter = Filter<Language>.empty
```

Make sure your `Language` type properly conforms to the `FilterOption` protocol:

```
struct Language: FilterOption { 
    // Fulfill the requirements of the FilterOption protocol
}
```

As soon as you do that you are good to create your empty filter.